# How to add an image and text to the same cell pdfbox?

Tags: pdfbox, boxable

Is there any way to insert an image along with a text in a cell of a table using PDFBox 2? That is, text aligned at the top and the image centered, both within the same cell?

Answer (score 1):

The github cross-post of this question has been answered by boxable development:

> Frulenzo commented 5 days ago
>
> That is not avaiable. You can have either text or image only because image and text alignment is royal pain

*([dhorions/boxable issue #138](https://github.com/dhorions/boxable/issues/138#issuecomment-355309446))*

Thus, there currently is no way to do so supported by boxable.